# My webview app open on top of another app

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, deep-linking

When clicking on a link in another application (my application is not started), my application will open on top of that app. 
For example, if someone clicks the link to my app from telegram, it opens my app over top of Telegram app. Even, I can't see my app on the recent app list.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrX4C.jpg)

AndroidManifest file:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="app.freeairdrop.io">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:appCategory="productivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name="app.freeairdrop.io.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
            android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:supportsPictureInPicture="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="freeairdrop.io" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>
    </application>


    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

For your every activity `android:excludeFromRecents="true"`

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```